# javafx open a new fxml file in new tab dynamically

Tags: java, tabs, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am creating a javafx program in which i need to open a new fxml file in new tab dynamically.

I want that When user click on `button` a new tab is opened with `new fxml file`.

I Had no idea I can add tab as per design as much as i need but i want to do it `dynamically` when user click on `button` then only a new tab open.

I had also seen [Questing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146362/how-to-load-content-to-javafx-tabs-dynamically) but not working for me.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tabs dynamically with

```
myTabPane.getTabs().add(myNewTab);
```

Create a new Tab with `new Tab()`, load your FXML and call

```
myNewTab.setContent(loadedFxmlRoot);
```

Comment: This is the simplicity I’ve been searching for in the “adding tabs dynamically” subject, but can you provide an example of this that includes more detail and the order in which things are done? For example, you say “Create a new Tab with new Tab()", but is that doing something like this: Tab newTab = new Tab(); then is that used in the .add(newTab) line??  A working example would clear everything up for me I think. I would greatly appreciate it.  Mike

Comment: It looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464411/how-to-create-tabs-dynamically-in-javafx-using-fxml?lq=1 has the example I’m looking for ... I’ll update my comments as necessary over the next hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tabs using this code, you need to confirm if your tabPane has this tab or no, else your program invokes SizeOfBounds exception.

```
if (!MessagePane.getTabs().contains(AllMessageTab)) {
    MessagePane.getTabs().add(AllMessageTab);
}
SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = MessagePane.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.select(AllMessageTab);        
AllMessageTab.setContent(_YourContentNodeHere);
```